# Show and hide html element on selected option change

Tags: javascript, jquery, html, jsp

In a JSP page, I have a dropdown list. When the first element of the list is selected, I want a text area to show right on click. I'm new to Javascript/Jquery, so I'm obviously missing something in the function (the text area never shows up). Hope someone can help.

This is the HTML:

```
<tr class="odd gradeX">
    <td class="col-lg-3">
        <div>
            <label>Show text area</label>
            <select id="show" class="form-control" name="show_text_area" onchange="change()">
                <option value="1">YES</option>
                <option value="0">NO</option>
            </select>

        </div>
    </td>
    <td class="col-lg-3">
        <div>
            <label>Text area</label>
            <textarea id="text_area" class="form-control" type="text" name="text_area" placeholder="Write something" rows="5" cols="50" style="display: none"></textarea>
        </div>
    </td>
</tr>
```

This is the function, on top of the JSP:

```
<script> function change() {
    var selectBox = document.getElementById("show");
    var selected = selectBox.options[selectBox.selectedIndex].value;
    var textarea = document.getElementById("text_area");
    if(selected === '1'){
        textarea.show();
    }
    else{
        textarea.hide();
    }
});</script>
```

Comment: Instead of this `var selected = selectBox.options[selectBox.selectedIndex].value;` just use `var selected = selectBox.value;`

Answer (score 10, accepted):

You have mistake at the end of your function - remove the last );

Finally it should be:

```
<select id="show" class="form-control" name="show_text_area" onchange="change(this)">


function change(obj) {


    var selectBox = obj;
    var selected = selectBox.options[selectBox.selectedIndex].value;
    var textarea = document.getElementById("text_area");

    if(selected === '1'){
        textarea.style.display = "block";
    }
    else{
        textarea.style.display = "none";
    }
}
```

Answer (score 4):

You can use jQuery as following

```
<script> function change() {
    var selectBox = document.getElementById("show");
    var selected = selectBox.options[selectBox.selectedIndex].value;

    if(selected === '1'){
        $('#text_area').show();
    }
    else{
        $('#text_area').hide();
    }
}</script>
```

Comment: I had to remove the last ) for it to work, but it did the job for me when I did.

Answer (score 2):

1. Use jQuery.
2. Remove `onchange="change()"` function from

   ```
   <select id="show" class="form-control" name="show_text_area" onchange="change()">
   ```
3. Look for change event, on your select element.

   ```
   $('#show').on('change', function () {
      var optionSelected = $("option:selected", this);
      var valueSelected = this.value;
      if(valueSelected == 1){
          $("#text_area").show();
      } else {
          $("#text_area").hide();
      }
   });
   ```

[Fiddle](http://jsfiddle.net/7ooy17qj/)

Answer (score 1):

you can use jquery also.

```
$('#show').val();
   if( $('#show').val() == "1")
    {
         $('#text_area').show(); 
              OR
           $("#text_area").css("visibility", "visible");
   }else
   {
      $('#text_area').hide(); 
              OR
           $("#text_area").css("visibility", "hidden");
  }
```

Answer (score 1):

Try this code:

```
// This will create an event listener for the change action on the element with ID 'show'
$('#show').change(function() {

     // If checkbox is 'checked'
    if($(this).is(':checked')) {
        // show the element that has the id 'txt_area' 
        $('#text_area').show();
    } else {
        // hide it when not checked
        $('#text_area').hide();
    }
});
```

Comment: Rather than just posting code (unformatted) explain why the code works, or what the user did wrong.

Comment: Thanks for the suggestion Styphon. I would have explained it. Will take care from next time

Comment: This is what I was looking for, something I understood already and could easily copy and paste into my project without much formatting needed.

Answer (score 0):

You can do also using jQuery as follows.

```
$("#show").change(function(){
   if($(this).val()=="1")
   {    
       $("#text_area").show();
   }
   else
   {
       $("#text_area").hide();
   }
});
```

**[Demo](http://jsfiddle.net/n1fjo6qu/1/)**

Answer (score 0):

```
var drpVal=  $('#show').val();
if( drpVal == "1")
{
     $('#text_area').show(); 
          // or u can use
       $("#text_area").css("display", "");
 }
 else{
  $('#text_area').hide(); 
          // or u can use
       $("#text_area").css("display", "none");
 }
```

Answer (score 0):

you can do this in jQuery.....like 
"
    $(document).ready(function(){

```
var seletVal=$('#show option:selected').val();
if(selectVal=='1')
$('#textareaId').show();
else
$('#textareaId').hide();
});
```

"

Answer (score 0):

You are getting the html element by **document.getElementById** that returns normal javascript object.
Jquery methods **hide()** and **show()** are available for **jquery objects only.**

But whatever you want to achieve can be achieved by simple Javascript, just made some simple changes.

**instead of show() and hide() use respectively `textarea.style.display = "block"` and  `textarea.style.display = "none"`;**

and remove the `);` in the end of your code.

use the fiddle link for working example. [fiddle link](http://jsfiddle.net/zb5k95dv/5/)

Answer (score -1):

Your function is correct, but js Element class have no show() and hide() methods. You can implement it using prototype. As an example

```
Element.prototype.hide(){
this.style.display = "hidden";
} 
Element.prototype.show(style){
style = style ? style : "block";
this.style.display = style;
}
```

But better use jquery or something like this.