# Javascript function to display image based on selection not working

Tags: javascript, html

I am trying to display a green, yellow, or red dot image depending on what color the user selects. I based my code on something I found on [this question](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/17879622/using-javascript-how-can-i-display-an-image-if-the-value-of-2-fields-are-equal).

For some reason, the function is not working. Currently nothing happens when the user makes a selection.

```js
var statusCode = document.getElementById('statusCode');
var greenDot = document.getElementById('greenDot');
var yellowDot = document.getElementById('yellowDot');
var redDot = document.getElementById('redDot');

function myfunction() {
  if (statusCode.value == 'Green') {
    greenDot.style.display = 'circle';
    yellowDot.style.display = 'none';
    redDot.style.display = 'none';
  } 
  else if (statusCode.value == 'Yellow') {
    greenDot.style.display = 'none';
    yellowDot.style.display = 'circle';
    redDot.style.display = 'none';
  } 
  else if (statusCode.value == 'Red') {
    greenDot.style.display = 'none';
    yellowDot.style.display = 'none';
    redDot.style.display = 'circle';
  }
}
```

```html
<select id="statusCode" onload="myFunction()">
  <option value="Green">Green</option>
  <option value="Yellow">Yellow</option>
  <option value="Red">Red</option>
</select>

<p>
  <img src="http://clipart-library.com/image_gallery/156788.png" style="display: none;" id="greenDot">
  <img src="http://www.clker.com/cliparts/o/b/y/x/Z/c/yellow-dot-md.png" style="display: none;" id="yellowDot">
  <img src="http://www.clker.com/cliparts/s/o/v/c/T/Y/red-dot-md.png" style="display:none;" id="redDot">
</p>
```

Comment: There is no such thing as `display = 'circle';` You have [a limited number of choices for what to set `display` to](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/CSS/display). You likely want "inline-block" or "block";

Comment: Possible duplicate of [Show and hide html element on selected option change](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/27921922/show-and-hide-html-element-on-selected-option-change)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I fix a little your code:

- change way of read select value (in line `let value =....`)
- change html `<select ... onload...` to `oninput`
- change js `myfunction` to `myFunction` (F uppercase)
- change in js `style.display = 'circle'` to `'block'`
- call `myFunction()` in script bottom to init first picture
- change `<img src=http://...` to `https://` (but may be this was needed only here in SO)

```js
var statusCode = document.getElementById('statusCode');
var greenDot = document.getElementById('greenDot');
var yellowDot = document.getElementById('yellowDot');
var redDot = document.getElementById('redDot');

function myFunction() {

    const value = statusCode.options[statusCode.selectedIndex].value

    if(value == "Green") {        
        greenDot.style.display = 'block';
        yellowDot.style.display = 'none';
        redDot.style.display = 'none';
    }
    else if(value == "Yellow"){
        greenDot.style.display = 'none';
        yellowDot.style.display = 'block';
        redDot.style.display = 'none';
    }
    else if(value == "Red"){
        greenDot.style.display = 'none';
        yellowDot.style.display = 'none';
        redDot.style.display = 'block';
    }
}

myFunction();
```

```html
<select id="statusCode" onchange="myFunction()"> 
  <option value="Green">Green</option>
  <option value="Yellow">Yellow</option>
  <option value="Red">Red</option>
</select>

<p>    
  <img src="https://clipart-library.com/image_gallery/156788.png" style="display: none;" id="greenDot"/>
  <img src="https://www.clker.com/cliparts/o/b/y/x/Z/c/yellow-dot-md.png" style="display: none;" id="yellowDot"/>
  <img src="https://www.clker.com/cliparts/s/o/v/c/T/Y/red-dot-md.png" style="display:none;" id="redDot"/>
</p>
```

Comment: Well, `statusCode.value` is still shorter and easier to remember.

Comment: Also, I think you want to use `onchange` for a `<select>` element. Also, why use inline JS at all...? Might raise an `unsafe-inline` flag in special cases, and looking forward to separation of concerns an `addEventListener` would be better.

Comment: @RokoC.Buljan you have right. If this was my code, I will write it completely different - however the OP is probably beginner so i focus only on fix bugs int code to make it works (with minimal changes to original code) - not to refactor it.

Comment: I was always glad, in my early days, when someone helped me refactor my code - to speed up my learning curve and not repeat some basic mistakes ;)

Answer (score 0):

There are a few mistakes with the code

1. The event handler for the dropdown is `onchange`
2. The `myfunction` is case sensitive
3. Set the visible dot to display `block` or some other value (https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/CSS/display)

Comment: I tried onchange as well and in my actual code myFunction has correct capitalization not sure what happened here. I didn't think that 'circle' would display but I tested it and it worked so I just went with it. Thank you for your help.

Comment: By such answers people might think w3schools is an authoritative resource worth learning from. They've done and still do so much harm to the programming community by providing low quality and inadequate documentation. They even sell worthless and fake diplomas.

Answer (score 0):

Here’s a method of creating this status dot without any images at all, using a bit of CSS:

```js
// Get references to the relevant elements
const statusCode = document.getElementById('statusCode');
const dot = document.getElementById('dot');

// Register an event handler for the select menu’s change event
statusCode.addEventListener('change', e => {
  // Remove all existing color classes
  dot.classList.remove('dot-red', 'dot-yellow', 'dot-green');

  // Apply the correct color class using the value of the select menu
  dot.classList.add(`dot-${e.target.value}`);
});

// Manually trigger the event once to set the initial color
statusCode.dispatchEvent(new Event('change'));
```

```css
.dot {
  /* Setup dimension */
  width: 10px;
  height: 10px;

  /* Make the dot round (side length / 2) */
  border-radius: 5px;

  /* Set a default color */
  background-color: black;

  /* Position the dot next to the menu */
  display: inline-block;

  /* Apply a light shadow to make low contrast colors more visible */
  box-shadow: 0 0 5px gray;
}

.dot-red {
  background-color: red;
}

.dot-yellow {
  background-color: yellow;
}

.dot-green {
  background-color: lime;
}
```

```html
<select id="statusCode">
  <option value="green">Green</option>
  <option value="yellow">Yellow</option>
  <option value="red">Red</option>
</select>

<div id="dot" class="dot"></div>
```

Comment: Thank you for your solution! I went with another because I was more familiar with it. I did upvote you but I don't have a good enough reputation for it show.

Answer (score 0):

Imagine one day, your colleague asks you to add **50 (or *N*) status codes**.
Copy-paste the `if` statements, each 52 lines long, 50 times and manually naming the elements that should become hidden is not the right way to approach the problem and programming in general.
There are many ways, I'll show you one:

- Don't use HTML-inline javascript, use `Element.addEventListener()` instead - Look forward to keep your JS in one place, not separated in different places (HTML and JS files)
- Assign to your images a `data-id` attribute **that have the same value** as the Option elements `value`.
- Use `Element.classList` and it's methods to `remove()` or `add()` a class (see CSS)

the following will now work for an indefinite number of elements:

```js
const status = document.querySelector('#statusCode');
const parent = document.querySelector('#images');
const allImg = parent.querySelectorAll('[data-id]'); // get them all!

function showImage() {
  allImg.forEach(el => el.classList.remove('is-visible'));       // Hide all images
  const img = parent.querySelector(`[data-id="${this.value}"]`); // Find image by data-id
  if (img) {
    img.classList.add('is-visible'); // Show it (if found)
  }
}

statusCode.addEventListener('change', showImage);
```

```css
#images [data-id] {
  display: none;
}

#images [data-id].is-visible {
  display: block;
}
```

```html
<select id="statusCode">
  <option disabled selected>-Select status color-</option>
  <!-- values should reflect exactly the images data-id value -->
  <option value="green">Green</option>
  <option value="yellow">Yellow</option>
  <option value="red">Red</option>
</select>

<div id="images">
  <img data-id="green"  src="//placehold.it/50x50/0f0">
  <img data-id="yellow" src="//placehold.it/50x50/ff0">
  <img data-id="red"    src="//placehold.it/50x50/f00">
</div>
```

and even the above code can be further improved for even (yet just slightly) better performance.

---

Resources:

https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Learn/HTML/Howto/Use_data_attributes
https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/API/EventTarget/addEventListener
https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/API/NodeList/forEach
https://developer.mozilla.org/en/docs/Web/API/Element/classList